# If 900 out of 1000 people say a car is blue, what is the probability that it is blue?

Tags: probability

This initially arose in connection some work we are doing to a model to classify natural text, but I've simplified it... Perhaps too much.

You have a blue car (by some objective scientific measure - it is blue).

You show it to 1000 people.

900 say it is blue. 100 do not.

You give this information to someone who cannot see the car. All they know is that 900 people said it was blue, and 100 did not. You know nothing more about these people (the 1000).

Based on this, you ask the person, "What is the probability that the car is blue?"

This has caused a huge divergence of opinion amongst those I have asked! What is the right answer, if there is one?

Comment: I wonder what the answers would be if you changed *car* to *dress*.

Comment: So what is the question to people? "Is the car blue?" or "What color is the car?"

Comment: What does it mean for the car to be blue? If some people say the car is not blue, then it is likely that it is a colour that some people call blue and others call by a different name. This does not mean they disagree on the colour it means they disagree on the name of the colour.

Comment: I think the question would be improved a lot if you gave the different divergent opinions you encountered. As it stands now, answers can just explore the whole field, from probability theory to color theory or even biology (color blindness) wildly, and I don't see how that would really help you.

Comment: If you know the car is blue, how does it help to ask 1000 people whether it is blue or not? Conversely, if you do not know that the car is blue, what rational explanation do you proffer as to why 100 people say it is not blue? Do they all live on the island of Pingelap?

Comment: There's something missing in the problem description. 100 people denying that the car is blue when it's certainly blue is a lot of people, you can't simply discard them as random errors.

Comment: Presumably you didn't ask any electric monks about the color of the car.  -> "The Monk currently believed that the valley and everything in the valley and around it, including the Monk itself and the Monk's horse, was a uniform shade of pale pink."

Comment: 100 do not? Do they say the car is a different color or do they have no opinion?

Comment: What about purple? I find much fewer people agree what purple is.

Comment: Is this problem (meant to be) equivalent to 'coin is heads up'?

Comment: Ok, maybe 100 were color blind.

Comment: The original opinions ranged from .. 1) cannot answer 2) need more information 3) need this (specific) additional information 4) 90% 5) 100% 6) Almost 100% 7) Certain 8) Almost certain 9) Stupid question - you already said the car was blue! And then all the comments and explanations that went along side the answers. Much of this is echoed here!

Comment: I'm going with 9

Comment: The car is either blue or it is not blue. That is a physical reality that does not change depending on the outcome of a poll.\

Comment: Was the data collected on one side of $t$ in Goodman's "[New Riddle of Induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_induction#Nelson_Goodman.27s_new_riddle_of_induction)"  and on the other side of $t$ you ask the one person "What is the probability that the car is blue?"  What if you don't know when $t$ is relative to your process?

Comment: I strongly disagree with @SinanÜnür, being blue is not a physical reality by any stretch of the imagination, it's a psychological and cultural reality. And as it turns one that has been studied extensively with blue being an interesting corner case. There are European languages/cultures with an obligatory distinction between two types of blue (no single word or concept for “blue”) and others with a single word for blue and green.

Comment: Even more intriguing, when speakers of the latter type of languages are asked to choose a typical example of blue/green, they tend to pick either a typical blue or a typical green (i.e. a colour that speakers of other languages choose as typical “green” or typical “blue” when asked the same question) and *not* something in-between. It seems that's not at all what your question was trying to get at but it's funny you would choose that example.

Comment: On a more esoteric line.. Try the colour of the Scottish flag, which is "Azure", which is said to be the colour of the sky, so almost any old blue colour will do... At the moment you only have a statistic. You need a theory to get a probability ;-)

Comment: maybe I don't understand something, but it looks like it should be 90%

Comment: The probability of the car being blue is 1(or 0 if it is not actually blue). The car is either blue or it is not, since blue is definition, the car is either "blue by definition" or it is not. Basically it just depends on if who ever decides color names. The likelihood the car is blue given 900 out of 1000 people say it is, is 0.9.   It's sort of like flipping a coin: the probability of an ideal flip is heads will land is either 0 or 1. The probability of a yet to occur flip of a heads is 0.5.

Comment: You are saying "it is blue" like it's an objectively measurable fact. In this case you will need to carefully define what you mean by it so that it can be tested by an objective experiment. For example maybe in terms of wavelengths of light it reflects, does not reflect and partially reflects.

Comment: You have a patient known to have Molloy's Syndrome. You administer a test 1000 times; 900 times they test positive for Molloy's Syndrome; 100 times they test negative. Now you tell a stranger *only* that the test came up positive 900 times and negative 100 times; you do not tell them (1) the incidence of Molloy's Syndrome in the population at large, (2) the fact that we have solid evidence that there is a 10% false negative rate, and (3) that we have zero evidence for what the false positive rate might be. How can they *possibly* guess at the probability of a true positive?

Comment: The "test" might be "roll a ten sided die and report positive if it comes up 1-9" for all the stranger knows. If my scenario is different in some fashion than your blue car scenario, *what is the germane difference*?

Comment: ~8% of the cars in North America are blue. YMMV

Comment: The car must be _amazingly_ blue if 900 out of 1000 people chose to comment on its color without being asked anything.

Comment: 90% of the cars in the UK are blue.

Comment: Where are the 1000 people from, and is English their first language? Many languages and cultures [don't distinguish between blue and green](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue%E2%80%93green_distinction_in_language).

Comment: 0%: The car is navy, but you polled 900 normies, and 100 fine arts majors, graphic designers, and others who know how to recognize colors.

Comment: Ultimately the answer depends on the desired result. Typically color names are assigned to ranges of color spectrum that are culturally accepted as belonging to that name. 

There are scientific definitions of "blue", but they are narrow & marginally useful if your goal is to, say, build a classifier that determines if an image contains blue, or characterize the color of an object - usages that require a cultural definition.

Comment: If you want to know if something is culturally-defined "blue", then the probability of it being blue is the same as the percentage of people in that culture who classified it as blue. If you're using a scientific definition of blue, you can obtain the answer by comparing your human answers against e.g. color-spectrum data and get an objective answer. This answer will be in one of 4 categories according to all permutations of true and false for each category.

Comment: To make the question interesting, you should dispense with the bit about the car being objectively, factually, blue, and suppose that the only information we have about the car color is the set of subjective opinions from 1000 people.

Comment: For those interested, I suggest reading about [Information cascades](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_cascade). Is really interesting as it shows how our prediction on the outcome is affected by the previous *predictions*, when considering them in a conditional probabilistic approach. This happens in natural systems, like swarms, economic speculation, games of chance, and others.

Comment: Being an experimental scientist my first instinct is to quiz you about the nature of the 'certain'ty of blueness and the accuracy you expect from the people you polled. I generally wouldn't expect a 10% error rate on a yes/no evaluation of a 'certain' condition, unless the instrument has a significant uncertainty (which may be reasonable if we really are talking about people and color identification, but then I would find the claim to factual blueness to be overstated). I'd want to undertake some mini-studies to determine if blueness is more subtle or complicated than I previously believed.

Comment: It sounds to me that what the OP really wants isn't probability, it's fuzzy logic. This is exactly the kind of problem fuzzy logic was invented to solve.

Comment: The missing information is -- what is the probability that the average person is correct when reporting whether a car is blue or not blue. The evidence demonstrates that this probability must be either 0.9 or 0.1. Knowing which probability is the correct one is identical to knowing whether the car is blue; if you know either fact then you know the other.

Comment: I would say probably not blue. Most people have a somewhat limited color vocabulary, but a substantial minority have a more extensive color vocabulary. Furthermore, those with the larger vocabulary tend to use it correctly. Thus. if 100 out of 1000 people say that it isn't blue but 900 say that it is, the most likely explanation is that the color is *close* to blue but really isn't (perhaps it is periwinkle), a fact that 100 people correctly pick up on, but the 900 people with a cruder vocabulary pick the word that they know which is closest to the true color.

Comment: Interestingly, Ruben van Bergen, amoeba, and gnasher729 offer the opinion that the probability of any reporter being accurate must be 0.9 and therefore the car is blue, while guenthmonstr and John Coleman present good arguments that the probability of accuracy must be 0.1 and therefore the car is not blue.

Comment: First, because you stated "by some objective scientific measure - it is blue" and then asked the question "What is the probability that the car is blue?", the probability is 100% that it's blue, regardless of what people said.  However, if you didn't know what color the car was and asked 1000 people who had seen it, you still have some issues -- the 900 could have been Trump supporters who heard on Fox news that the car was blue, despite what their own eyes told them.  Or they could have been paid by the person selling the car to say it was blue because that's the color you're looking for.

Comment: Actually, the bribery notion would adequately explain the 100 people who said it wasn't blue -- they're simply folks who couldn't be bought.

Comment: 5-8% depending on the region: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Car_colour_popularity

Comment: Keep in mind that 8% of males and 1 out of 200 women are colorblind, so it is safe to assume that the car is blue in this case if 90% of the participants say that it is blue.

Comment: I’d guess only a bit more than 50% (chance) because, with such a large amount of poll results, 10% outlyers are a red flag (no colour pun intended) that can invalidate the other answers. But I guess it all comes down to interpretation.

Comment: This must rank as the over-rated question on stats StackExchange

Comment: Why must a cars' color be binary and why can't it be a probability distribution or some kind of a confidence measure? @wolfies: quite yes, but there do exist worse examples. It sure matters what shade of sunglasses I use when I look at cars.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with probability.  It's a question of the physics of colors, and how colors are determined.  Using humans to classify colors is just about the least reliable way to do it, as many are color-blind to one extent or another or have cultural biases as to what particular shades are called.  And "blue" is a very vague description of a color, with no indication as to whether it should be discriminated from, say, "greenish-blue".  Get 1000 physicists to analyze the color using spectral analysis and then you MIGHT have something you could apply statistics to.

Comment: @DanielRHicks, actually, it's not a physics question. Otherwise, it's a survey of humans, so even if they observe the objective reality their answers will have variations due to perceptions and other factors. That's why the question is interesting.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

**TL;DR: Unless you assume people are unreasonably bad at judging car color, or that blue cars are unreasonably rare, the large number of people in your example means the probability that the car is blue is basically 100%.**

Matthew Drury already gave the right answer but I'd just like to add to that with some numerical examples, because you chose your numbers such that you actually get pretty similar answers for a wide range of different parameter settings. For example, let's assume, as you said in one of your comments, that the probability that people judge the color of a car correctly is 0.9. That is: 
$$p(\text{say it's blue}|\text{car is blue})=0.9=1-p(\text{say it isn't blue}|\text{car is blue})$$
and also
$$p(\text{say it isn't blue}|\text{car isn't blue})=0.9=1-p(\text{say it is blue}|\text{car isn't blue})$$

Having defined that, the remaining thing we have to decide is: what is the prior probability that the car is blue? Let's pick a very low probability just to see what happens, and say that $p(\text{car is blue})=0.001$, i.e. only 0.1% of all cars are blue. Then the posterior probability that the car is blue can be calculated as:

\begin{align*}
&p(\text{car is blue}|\text{answers})\\
&=\frac{p(\text{answers}|\text{car is blue})\,p(\text{car is blue})}{p(\text{answers}|\text{car is blue})\,p(\text{car is blue})+p(\text{answers}|\text{car isn't blue})\,p(\text{car isn't blue})}\\
&=\frac{0.9^{900}\times 0.1^{100}\times0.001}{0.9^{900}\times 0.1^{100}\times0.001+0.1^{900}\times0.9^{100}\times0.999}
\end{align*}

If you look at the denominator, it's pretty clear that the second term in that sum will be negligible, since the relative size of the terms in the sum is dominated by the ratio of $0.9^{900}$ to $0.1^{900}$, which is on the order of $10^{58}$. And indeed, if you do this calculation on a computer (taking care to avoid numerical underflow issues) you get an answer that is equal to 1 (within machine precision).

The reason the prior probabilities don't really matter much here is because you have so much evidence for one possibility (the car is blue) versus another. This can be quantified by the *likelihood ratio*, which we can calculate as:
$$
\frac{p(\text{answers}|\text{car is blue})}{p(\text{answers}|\text{car isn't blue})}=\frac{0.9^{900}\times 0.1^{100}}{0.1^{900}\times 0.9^{100}}\approx 10^{763}
$$

So before even considering the prior probabilities, the evidence suggests that one option is already astronomically more likely than the other, and for the prior to make any difference, blue cars would have to be unreasonably, stupidly rare (so rare that we would expect to find 0 blue cars on earth).

So what if we change how accurate people are in their descriptions of car color? Of course, we could push this to the extreme and say they get it right only 50% of the time, which is no better than flipping a coin. In this case, the posterior probability that the car is blue is simply equal to the prior probability, because the people's answers told us nothing. But surely people do at least a little better than that, and even if we say that people are accurate only 51% of the time, the likelihood ratio still works out such that it is roughly $10^{13}$ times more likely for the car to be blue.

This is all a result of the rather large numbers you chose in your example. If it had been 9/10 people saying the car was blue, it would have been a very different story, even though the same ratio of people were in one camp vs. the other. Because statistical evidence doesn't depend on this ratio, but rather on the numerical difference between the opposing factions. In fact, in the likelihood ratio (which quantifies the evidence), the 100 people who say the car isn't blue exactly cancel 100 of the 900 people who say it is blue, so it's the same as if you had 800 people all agreeing it was blue. And that's obviously pretty clear evidence.

(Edit: [As Silverfish pointed out](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298917/if-900-out-of-1000-people-say-a-car-is-blue-what-is-the-probability-that-it-is#comment568182_298937), the assumptions I made here actually implied that whenever a person describes a non-blue car incorrectly, they will default to saying it's blue. This isn't realistic of course, because they could really say any color, and will say blue only some of the time. This makes no difference to the conclusions though, since the less likely people are to mistake a non-blue car for a blue one, the stronger the evidence that it is blue when they say it is. So if anything, the numbers given above are actually only a lower bound on the pro-blue evidence.)

Comment: +1. In fact, given OP's data, the MLE estimate of how often people are accurate is 900/1000=90%.

Comment: Getting a car colour correct 50% of the time is not the same as flipping a coin. After all, there are way more than just two available colours. Also, maybe some say "navy" or "azure" instead of "blue"? Actually, mayn people will wrongly say "blue" when the correct answer would be "some fancy and fashionable patented colour that almost looks like blue"

Comment: I know these are just illustrative figures, but if "the probability that people judge the color of a car correctly is 0.9" then, unless there is something special about the colour blue, I don't think it is reasonable to claim p(say it's blue|car isn't blue)=0.1. If we think that 90% of the time, people identify the correct colour, then p(say red|car is red)=p(say white|car is white)=p(say green|car is green)=0.9 and so on for all possible car colours. But why should p(say blue|car is red)=p(say blue|car is white)=p(say blue|car is green)=0.1? This would imply e.g. p(say white|car is red)=0.

Comment: @Silverfish: Ah shoot you're right of course! Assuming 90% accuracy, if the car isn't blue they have a 10% chance of saying it's another color than what it actually is, but that wrongly identified color can be anything, not just blue. So actually that probability probably ought to be quite a bit lower. I'd have to think about how that affects the results but my guess is not much...

Comment: Okay having thought about it a bit more, the 0.1 figure (or more generally 1-accuracy) is an upper bound for the probability that a person will say blue when the car isn't blue. It would be exactly right if people always said blue whenever they were mistaken, but the real figure is certainly lower. This would mean that the 0.1 in the denominator of the likelihood ratio would be smaller, which only increases the likelihood ratio further, and so the argument holds.

Comment: (In a more sophisticated model, we might even take into account that a colour may be more likely misidentified as one colour than another, e.g. p(say purple|car is purple)=0.9, p(say blue|car is purple)=0.05, p(say white|car is purple)=0.001... but even without going into such depths, it seems to me that the current assignments privilege blue as a special colour. Apologies for reposting the comment but I noticed a critical typo and it was too late to edit!)

Comment: In my original phrasing, perhaps not clear enough, I had in mind 'blue' and 'not blue' .. i.e binary .. the 'not blue' group could contain any colours. Given that, I think that if 500 people say blue and 500 say not blue, that is exactly equivalent to a coin toss?

Comment: @PatMolloy: Not necessarily. It depends on whether the probabilities are symmetrical: is it equally likely that someone mistakes a blue for a non-blue car, as it is that someone mistakes a non-blue for a blue car? If so, then a 500/500 verdict gives exactly as much information as a coin toss. But if people are less likely to say a non-blue car is blue, than they are to say that a blue car is not blue, then the 500 blue-sayers are harder to explain away than the 500 not blue-sayers, under the not-blue hypothesis. So in that case the balance of evidence would tilt towards blue.

Comment: I think it's plausible for people to consistently misidentify the color of a car. Most people (perhaps 900 out of 1,000?) identify these cars as black, even though they're not. http://i.imgur.com/hx4edG6.png

Comment: To push this Bayes-Theorem boat out one level further, you could consider the probability that the observers are truthfully telling you what they internally think. Remember, the data is not that they *perceived* the car as blue, but that they *said* it is blue. But this is of course pathological overkill, for everyday situations... it just illustrates that Bayes' Theorem is a great tool for converting chains of assumptions into numerical estimates.

Comment: Colour perception's a tricky thing.. if nine out of ten people say a [dress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_dress) is white and gold, what's the probability it's blue and black?

Comment: Would it be correct to also add (although it doesn't matter since it gets cancelled out) an nCr term to represent that there are 1000C100 ways of getting those answers?

Comment: @user1936752: Yes, good point. Since you're conditioning on the observed outcome, and comparing different hypotheses to explain that outcome, all you really need to consider is how much more likely (in terms of ratios) one hypothesis is vs. another. And so because that same combinatoric term shows up in the likelihood of all possible hypotheses, you can ignore its contribution. But if your goal was strictly to calculate e.g. $p(\text{answers}|\text{car is blue})$, you'd definitely need to include it.

Comment: You're assuming people's opinions are independent/uncorrelated, which is clearly false.

Comment: For comparison, there have been only 10^60 planck-times since the creation of the universe.

Comment: For $p\approx 1/2$, the likelihood ratio is roughly $\exp\{8n(f-1/2)(p-1/2)\}$ ($f$ is the fraction of people that say the car is blue).

Comment: "Unless you assume people are unreasonably bad at judging car color" - seems a pretty safe assumption to me; in fact I thought that's exactly what the question was trying to resolve.

Comment: What if most cars are blue and those 1000 people where asked to identify the color of the car during the night and therefore they just use their prior knowledge that most cars are blue when guessing the color of the car? Then, the fact that 90% of the people answered blue may actually reveal that 90% of the cars are blue and therefore the probability of the car being blue would be 90%.

Comment: One thing I noted is that you are not including uncertainty into your analysis. If you had a 50%/50% split for the color, and then 1 person switches, your likelihood ratio is 81 (98%/2%)! That is certainly wrong. No way can 1 person sway reality so much! You need to encode uncertainty in this Bayesian estimate!

Comment: @adian.plenert.macdonald: I'm not sure I follow. The likelihood ratio is directly linked to uncertainty, since uncertainty would be defined as something like the entropy of the posterior. So the more inequitable the likelihoods of blue vs. not blue, the smaller the uncertainty. Also note that your calculation of a ratio of 81 is based on an accuracy of 90%. The calculation is correct, but the probability of that situation (501/499 split given 90% accuracy) ever occurring is extremely small (the most likely split with 90% accuracy is 900/100). I think that's why the result is surprising.

Comment: @adian.plenert.macdonald: To make this a bit more concrete, given 90% accuracy the probability of a 500/500 split is on the order of $10^{-223}$. The probability of a 501/499 split in favor of the correct answer is about $10^{-222}$, and for 499/501 it is $10^{-224}$. So yes, the likelihood that the 501 people are correct is about 100 (or more precisely, 81) times higher than the likelihood that the 499 people are correct, but the whole situation is ultimately extremely improbable (less likely than finding the atom you were looking in a single random draw from all the atoms in the universe).

Answer (score 74):

The correct answer depends on information not specified in the problem, you will have to make some more assumptions to derive a single, definitive answer:

- The prior probability the car is blue, i.e. your belief that the car is blue given you have not yet asked anyone.
- The probability someone tells you the car is blue when it actually *is* blue, and the probability they tell you the car is blue when it actually *is not* blue.
- The probability that the car actually is blue when someone says it is, and the probability that the car is not blue, when someone says it is blue.

With these pieces of information, we can break the whole thing down with Bayes's formula to derive a posterior probability that the car is blue.  I'll focus on the case where we only ask one person, but the same reasoning can be applied to the case where you ask $1000$ people.

$$\begin{align*}
P_{post} (\text{car is blue}) &= P(\text{car is blue} \mid \text{say is blue}) P(\text{say is blue}) \\
& \ \ \ \ + P(\text{car is blue} \mid \text{say is not blue}) P(\text{say is not blue})
\end{align*}$$

We need to continue to further break down $P(\text{say is blue})$, this is where the prior comes in:

$$\begin{align*}
P(\text{say is blue}) = \ &P(\text{say is blue} \mid \text{car is blue}) P_{prior}(\text{car is blue}) \\
&+ P(\text{say is blue} \mid \text{car is not blue}) P_{prior}(\text{car is not blue})
\end{align*}$$

So two applications of Bayes's rule get's you there.  You'll need to determine the unspecified parameters based on either information you have about the specific situation, or by making some reasonable assumptions.

There are some other combinations of what assumptions you can make, based on:

$$ P(\text{say is blue} \mid \text{car is blue}) P(\text{car is blue}) = P(\text{car is blue} \mid \text{say is blue}) P(\text{say is blue}) $$

At the outset, you don't know any of these things.  So you must make some reasonable assumptions about three of them, and then the fourth is determined from there.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is incredibly helpful. I almost understand, but am perplexed by the first point - the prior probability that the car is blue. I am not sure I would have any expectation of colour, if I was pre-asked "There is a car. It has a colour, we asked 1000 people what the colour is and they said ..."

Comment: That's often the case.  Then you have two options, express your total lack of knowledge by assuming blue and not blue are equally likely.  Do a quick survey of the field, something like this can help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Car_colour_popularity

Comment: If I assume that 90% of the answers that are given are correct (I have not done the maths) this would suggest that the probability the car is actually blue, it very high ... which I guess is intuitively right. A lot of people have said 0.9. Some have refused to answer saying there is not enough data (but failing to say what that data is!).

Comment: @Matthew the problem with "blue and not blue is equally likely" is that it's not consistent; if we apply the same reasoning to each of the possible car colors, we end up with the claim that they all simultaneously have 50% chance (impossible with more than two colors by the laws of probability) and less than 50% chance (when you look at blue in the "not white" and "not red", which also leads to contradictions since the probability of any color cannot take multiple values)

Comment: Agreed.  I'd definitely recommend using a google search to determine the prior.

Comment: There is more unspecified information than this because the people's answer need not be independent (in fact, we *hope* that they are strongly correlated with the objective colour, hence far from independent). What if the answers are "overly" dependent? Say, we simply ask ten random pedestrians, but have each of them reply 100 times?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen True, and good point!

Comment: You cannot give a sensible answer without some notion of the prior probability. For example, if there are no blue cars in existence, then the probability that the car is blue is zero. If there are no non-blue cars, then the probability that the car is blue is one. With no prior probability, all you can say is that the probability that the car is blue is somewhere between zero and one. (Though, as the problem is stated, the probability that the car is blue is one since we're given that it's blue.)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen and MatthewDrury. In fact, what you also need to assume is not independence but [conditional independence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence). In other words $P(\text {Joe and Mary say blue} | \text {car is blue}) = P(\text {Joe says blue} | \text {car is blue}) \cdot P(\text {Mary says blue} | \text {car is blue})$.

Comment: @Glen_b: There are only two colours in the world, blue and not-blue. Admittedly both come in a variety of shades, especially not-blue.

Comment: (oupps, same comment than David Schwartz, i just saw). Another take on 'prior probability' would be not based on belief but on actual proportion of blue cars (although the latter can guide the former). Imagine no blue cars exist. Then the answer would be $0$. If only blue cars exist, the answer would be $100%$. It helps taking extreme examples to check probability formulas.

Comment: @YvesgereY Yup.  If you look above, I posted a wikipedia page with the population distribution of car colors by company.  I'll try to edit in some of these comment points when I get a chance.

Comment: Excelent answers already. For those interested in this fenomena, it is more formally defined and named as [Information cascades](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_cascade). There are several interesting papers about them and their modelling, like [Quantifying and Tracing Information Cascades in Swarms](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0040084) if anyone wants an interesting reading.

Answer (score 13):

There's an important assumption that your 1000 opinions don't share a systematic bias. Which is a reasonable assumption here, but could be important in other cases.

Examples might be:

- they all share a similar colorblindness (genetics in a population for example),
- they all saw the car at night under orange sodium street lighting,
- they all share a common culture in which blue is taboo or magically associated (which biases whether or not they describe any object as blue or use a cultural euphemism or whatever instead),
- they have all been told (or share a common belief) that if they do/don't answer some specific way, something good/bad will happen to them.....

It isn't likely in this case but its a significant implied assumption in other cases. It doesn't have to be that extreme either - transpose your question to some other domain and this will be a real factor.

Examples for each where your answer may be affected by a shared bias:

- ask if a tall thin glass holds more than an actually-identical short fat glass, but your 1000 respondents are very young children (shared misperception).
- ask 1000 people if walking under a ladder is dangerous (common cultural belief)
- ask 1000 married people if they love their partner/have had an affair, in circumstances where they believe their partner will know of their answer. The context might be a TV show, or partner present when asked etc (common belief about consequences)

It wouldn't be hard to imagine some structurally identical questions where the 900:100 response was a measure of beliefs and honesty, or something else, and doesn't point to the correct answer. Not likely in this case but in other cases - yes.

Answer (score 11):

One reason you're getting different answers from different people is that the question can be interpreted in different ways, and it isn't clear what you mean by "probability" here. One way to make sense of the question is to assign priors and reason using Bayes' rule as in Matthew's answer.

Before asking for probabilities, you have to decide what's modeled as random and what's not. It's not universally accepted that unknown but fixed quantities should be assigned priors. Here's a similar experiment to yours that highlights the problem with the question:

> Assume $X_i$, $i = 1, \dots, 1000$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables with success probability (mean) $p = 0.5$. For interpretability, let's think of the $X_i$ as coin flips. Suppose you observe (the sufficient statistic) $\sum_{i = 1}^{1000}X_i = 900$. What is the probability that the coin is fair?

From a frequentist perspective the question is either nonsensical or the answer is "one". If you're Bayesian maybe you want to assign a prior distribution to $p$, in which case the question makes sense. The fundamental difference between my example and the question is that $p$ is unknown in the question, and the question disguises the fact that the *actual* randomness is whether a (presumably randomly sampled) person answers that the car is blue or not. The car's color is not randomly assigned and thus it's uninteresting to speak of the probability of it being blue from a frequentist perspective.

Comment: So, if you remove the assumption that the car is blue, and the rest is the same, 900 people say is blue and 100 say is not, in that case the probability would be 0.9?

Comment: No, it's much much closer to 1. It is very, very unlikely that 900 out of 1000 people will get the color wrong.

Comment: `the probability is either one or zero, depending on whether the car is actually blue or not.` this does not correspond to an understanding of "probability" as I am familiar with it. It sounds a bit like "X can happen or can not happen, so the probability must be 50%". Can you make it a bit more clear what you mean by that sentence?

Comment: @AnoE the distinction is analogous to that between parameters and random variables. It is given in the setting of the question that the car is for a fact blue, it's color is not the result of a random experiment. It's essentially a frequentist v. Bayesian interpretation. If you flip a coin 1000 times and observe 900 heads, then what is the probability that the coin is fair? It's either one or zero if you're a frequentist (or nonsensical); we don't assign probabilities to parameters.

Comment: @user No, I've updated the answer to make my point clearer.

Comment: @Student001 thanks for updating it; it now is clear what you are intending to say. As it stood before, we would have had to look at the probability "p* = whether Student001 is a frequentist or a bayesian". :-D

Answer (score 7):

## Simple practical answer:

**The probability can easily range from 0% to 100% depending on your assumptions**

Though I really like the existing answers, in practice it basically boils down to these two simple scenarios:

#### Scenario 1: People are assumed to be *very* good at recognizing blue when it is blue ... 0%

In this case, there are so many people stating that the car is not blue, that it is very unlikely that the car is actually blue. Hence, the probability approaches 0%.

#### Scenario 2: People are assumed to be *very* good at recognizing not-blue when it is not-blue ... 100%

In this case, there are so many people stating that the car is blue, that it is very likely that it is indeed blue. Hence the probability approaches 100%.

---

Of course coming at this from a mathematical angle you would start by something generic like 'let us assume that the relevant probabilities are ...', which is quite meaningless as such things are typically not known for any random circumstance. Hence I advocate looking at the extremes to grasp the idea that both percentages can easily be justified with simple and realistic assumptions, and that there is therefore no single meaningful answer.

Comment: If "people are assumed to be very good at recognizing blue", why would they estimate it is blue when it isn't in scenario 1? You might want to express your scenarios in terms of false positivies and false negatives.

Comment: @hyde Reworded the scenarios to remove ambiguity

Comment: [False positive paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_positive_paradox)

Answer (score 5):

You need to develop some framework of estimation.  Some questions you might ask are

1. How many colors are there?  Are we talking two colors?  Or all the colors of the rainbow?
2. How distinct are the colors?  Are we talking blue and orange?  Or blue, cyan, and turquoise?
3. What does it mean to be blue?  Are cyan and/or turquoise blue?  Or just blue itself?
4. How good are these people at estimating color?  Are they all graphic designers?  Or are they color blind?

From a purely statistical standpoint, we can make some guesses as to the last one.  First, we know that at least 10% of the people are choosing an incorrect response.  If there are only two colors (from the first question), then we might say that there is

```
Probability says blue and is blue = 90% say is blue * 90% correct = 81%
Probability says blue and is not = 90% * 10% incorrect = 9%
Probability says not but is blue = 10% * 90% incorrect = 9%
Probability says not and is not = 10% * 10% = 1%
```

As a quick check, if we add those together, we get 100%.  You can see a more mathematical notation of this at the [@MatthewDrury answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/298922/174286).

How do we get the 90% in the third?  It's how many people said blue but were wrong if it's not.  Because there are only two colors, these are symmetric.  If there were more than two colors, then the chance of the wrong choice being blue when they said something else would be lower.

Anyway, this method of estimation gives us 90% blue.  This includes an 81% chance of people saying blue when it is and a 9% chance of people saying that it isn't when it is.  This is probably the closest we can come to answering the original question, and it requires us to rely on the data to estimate two different things.  And to assume that the chance of blue being chosen is the same as the chance of blue being correct.

If there are more than two colors, then the logic is going to change a bit.  The first two lines stay the same, but we lose the symmetry in the last two lines.  In that case, we need more input.  We might conceivably estimate the chance of correctly saying blue as 81% again, but we have no idea what the chances are that the color is blue when someone says that it is not.

We could also improve upon even the two color estimate.  Given a statistically significant number of cars of each color, we could have a statistically significant number of people view and categorize them.  Then we could count how often people are right when they make each color choice and how often they are right for each color choice.  Then we could estimate more accurately given people's actual choices.

You might ask how 90% could be wrong.  Consider what happens if there are three colors:  azure, blue, and sapphire.  Someone might reasonably consider all three of these to be blue.  But we want more.  We want the exact shade.  But who remembers the names of the other shades?  Many might guess blue because it is the only matching shade they know.  And still be wrong when it turns out to be azure.

Comment: As mentioned in one of the earlier comments, surely the only two relevant colors are 'blue' and 'not blue' hence the part about multiple colors should not be needed.

Answer (score 4):

An **exact, mathematical, true/false probability cannot be computed** with the information you provide.

However, in real life such information is never available with certainty. Therefore, using our intuition (and where all my money would go if we were betting), **the car is definitely blue.** (some believe this is not statistics anymore, but well, black/white views of science are not very helpful)

The reasoning is simple. Assume the car is not blue. Then 90% of the people (!) were wrong. They could only be wrong because of a list of issues including:

- [color blindness](https://nei.nih.gov/health/color_blindness/facts_about)
- [pathological lying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathological_lying)
- being under the influence of substances like alcohol, LCD, etc
- not understanding the question
- other form of mental disorder
- a combination of the above

Since the above is clearly not likely to affect 90% of an average random population (e.g. colour blindness affects around 8% of males and 0.6% of females, that is 43 people out of 1000), it is necessarily the case that the car is blue. (That is were all my money would go anyway).

Comment: This seems intuitively right to me. I think the criticism of the original question is that does not give enough information and that certain assumptions have to be made .. well, isn't that almost always the case in the real world???

Comment: @PatMolloy It does not give enough information to provide an exact right/wrong sophisticated mathematical answer (which is certainly what many questions aim to get from this site). However, given the reduced information that you gave, when it comes to betting money, this is the answer (100%) people will chose.

Comment: I think you have failed to cover some of the most plausible alternatives--which are ones that ought to cause you to modify your conclusion.  These include (a) people are unable to recognize blue; (b) there is no common understanding of "blue" between the questioner and the respondents; (c) the "scientific" meaning of "blue" differs from what people commonly understand as "blue." Importantly, because you cannot quantify *any* of these alternatives, nor most of those you list, how can you possibly justify quantifying the probability of the answer? That's not statistics!

Comment: "Since the above is clearly not likely to affect 90% of an average random population"

Don't be so sure about that.  Remember we generally talk in terms of averages when discussing humans.  So sure, only a few percent have color blindness (in comparison to the average), but there may be a distinct few who have superior vision, e.g. tetrachromats.

Comment: I'm always under the influence of LCD

Comment: My first intuition when hearing that only 90% of observers (who I assume are not part of some special population out of proportion with their numbers) can agree on what color something is, I take that to be a sign that there is some ambiguity. 

I'd have high certainty, greater than 90% that the car is blue under some definition of what blue is. But, to move the goalposts a bit, my estimate of *how blue* the car is would not be as high as if I only knew that a single person said the car is blue.

Comment: Most color-blind people can tell the difference between blue and any other color. It is really unlikely that a real life sample would contain 100 people asserting the car is red or yellow. That data has been tampered with and should be rejected.

Answer (score 2):

### What is the definition of "blue"?

Different cultures and languages have different notions of blue. IIRC, some cultures include green within their notion of blue!

Like any natural language word, you can only assume there is some cultural convention on when (and when not) to call things "blue".

Overall, [color in language is surprisingly subjective](https://vimeo.com/120808489) (link from the comments below, thanks @Count Ibilis)

[image]

Comment: In the context of the question, I believe this particular aspect is pretty irrelevant - I assume the OP chose the word "blue" as a very generic term and not something like "azure", "torqouise" etc. where people might be unsure. Also, cars usually tend to use a very limited palette of possible/usual colors. At last, the question is not "why did 100 people say non-blue", but "what probability that the car actually is blue".

Comment: https://vimeo.com/120808489

Comment: A precise definition would be "radiates light predominantly having a wavelength of 475nm plusminus ~10-20nm in present environmental conditions". This is generally accepted as blue.

Comment: Yes, but how many people carry along a tool to measure the predominant wavelength? You also forgot to exclude non-visible wavelengths.

Comment: Question seems to be about using a group of people of unknown calibration statistically as a wavelength meter :)

Comment: But then you have to accept that some consider turqoise to be blue, and others consider it to be distinct. People are "calibrated" differently also wrt. Language.

Comment: I agree with @rackandboneman I think that this point has to be taken into account. I think it most likely that the 10% were "wrong" because they are calibrated differently, not for other reasons. which makes the question either about the relationship between the current person's calibration and the "commonly accepted" one (which is probably some sort of average) OR between the current person's calibration and the average of the populations\'s (represented by the 1000) calibration. And I would guess these are the same?

Comment: Added a funny xkcd on exactly the topic of what color is.

Answer (score 2):

I would not eat feces based on the fact that billion of flies can't be wrong. There might dozens of other reasons why 900 people out of 1000 might have been cheated to think the car is blue. After all, that's the base of magical tricks, luring people into thinking something removed from reality.
If 900 people out of 1000 see a magician stabbing his/her assistant, they will promptly answer the assistant was stabbed, for how improbable an homicide happened on the stage. 
A blue light on a reflective car paint, anyone?

Answer (score 2):

The questionee knows too little about how the poll was carried out in order to answer the question accurately. As far as he's concerned, the poll can suffer from several problems:

The people taking the poll could have been biased:

1. The car [looked blue because of an optical illusion](https://www.google.se/search?q=is+the+dress+blue%3F&tbm=isch).
2. The color of the car was for some reason difficult to observe, and the people had for some reason been shown a lot of blue cars before this one, making most of them believe this car was probably blue, too.
3. You had paid them to say that the car is blue.
4. You had someone hypnotize all of them into believing that the car is blue.
5. They had made a pact to lie and sabotage the poll.

There may have been correlations among the people taking the poll because of how they were selected or because they affected each other:

1. You accidentally carried out the poll at a mass meeting for people with the same kind of color blindness.
2. You carried out the poll at kindergartens; the girls were not interested in the car and most of the boys had blue as their favorite color, making them imagine that the car was blue.
3. The first person who was shown the car was drunk and thought it looked blue, shouted "IT IS BLUE", influencing everyone else into thinking that the car was blue.

So while the probability that the car is blue if the poll was completely correctly carried out is extremely high (as explained in Ruben van Bergen's answer), the reliability of the poll may have been compromised which makes the chance that the car is not blue not insignificant. How big the questionee estimates this chance to be ultimately depends on his estimations of how likely it is that circumstances have screwed with the poll and of how good you are at carrying out polls (and how mischievous he thinks you are).

Answer (score 1):

The likelihood could, depending on more refined preconditions, be several different values, but 99.995% is the one that makes the most sense to me.

We know, by definition, that the car is blue (that's 100%), but it is not well-specified what this actually means (that would bet somewhat philosophical). I will assume something is blue in a sense of can-indeed-be-seen-as-blue.

We also know that 90% of test subjects reported it as blue.

We do *not* know what was asked or how the evaluation was done, and what lighting conditions the car was in. Being asked to name the color, some subjects might e.g. have said "greenish-blue" due to lighting conditions, and the assessor might not have counted that as "blue". The same people might have replied "yes" if the question had been "Is this blue?". I will assume that you did not intend to maliciously deceive your test subjects.

We know that the incidence of tritanopy is about 0,005% which means that if the car *could actually be seen as blue*, then 99.995% of the test subjects *indeed did see* the color as blue. That, however, means that 9.995% of the test subjects did not report blue when they clearly saw blue. They were lying about what they saw. This is close to what your life experience tells you as well: people are not always being honest (but, unless there's a motive, they usually are).

Thus, the non-observing person can assume with overwhelming certitude that the car is blue. That would be 100%

Except... except if the non-observing person herself suffers from tritanopy, in which case she would not see the car as blue even though everybody else (or rather, 90% of them) says so. Here it gets philosophical again: If everybody else heard a tree fall, but I didn't, did it fall?

I daresay that the most reasonable, practical answer would be: If the non-observing person happens to be trianope (0.005% chance), then *verifying* whether the predicted color and the real color as-seen are the same would yield false. Thus, the likelihood is 99.995% rather than 100%.

Further, as a bonus, since we found out that 9.995% of the test subjects are liars, and it is known that [all Cretans are liars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epimenides_paradox), we can conclude that we are not in Crete!

Answer (score 1):

> You have a blue car (by some objective scientific measure - it is
>   blue).
>
> ...
>
> "What is the probability that the car is blue?"

It is 100% blue.

> All they know is that 900 people said it was blue, and 100 did not. You know nothing more about these people (the 1000).

Using these numbers (without *any* context) is utterly nonsense. It all boils down to *personal* interpretation of the question. We should not go down this path and use Wittgenstein's: *"Wovon man nicht sprechen kann, darüber muss man schweigen."*

---

Imagine the following question for comparison:

```
All they know is that 0 people said it was blue, and 0 did not. 
You know nothing more about these people (the 0).
```

This is basically the same (information less) problem, but it is much more clear that what we think of the color of the car is mostly (if not completely) circumstantial.

---

In the long run, when we get multiple associated questions, then we are able to start guessing answers to such incomplete questions. This is the same for the tit-for-tat algorithm that doesn't work for a single case, [but it does work in the long run](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prisoner%27s_dilemma#The_iterated_prisoner's_dilemma). In the same sense Wittgenstein came back from his earlier work with his *Principal Investigations*. We are able to answer these questions, but we need more information/trials/questions. It is a process.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume the car is blue, then 100 out of 1,000 saying it's not blue implies an extreme sample bias of some kind. Perhaps you were sampling only colour-blind people. If we assume the car is not blue, then the sample bias is even worse. So all we can conclude from the data given is that the sample is very biased, and since we don't know how it was biased, we can't conclude anything about the colour of the car.

Comment: Umm, surely the fact that 900 people said it was blue is good for something? Can't we conclude it is more likely to be blue than not??  Remember the respondent only knows the numbers 900 and 100. So can they really say anything about bias?

Answer (score 0):

There have been some answers. I'm by no means a mathematics guru, but well, here is mine.

There can only be 4 possibilities:

```
case 1) Persons says car is blue and is correct
case 2) Person says car is blue and is incorrect
case 3) Person says car is not blue and is correct
case 4) Person says car is not blue and is incorrect
```

From the question, you know that the sum of case 1 and case 4 is 900 people (90%), and the sum of case 2 and case 3 is 100 people (10%). However here is the catch: what you don't know is the the distribution within these 2 case pairs. Maybe the sum of case 1 and 4 completely is made up of case 1 (which means car is blue), or perhaps the whole sum is made up of case 4 (which means car is not blue). Same goes for sum of case 2+3. So... What you need is to come up with some way to predict the distribution within case sums. With no other indication in the question (nowhere does it say people are 80% certain to know their colors or anything like that)  there is no way you can come up with a certain, definite answer.

Having said this... I do suspect the expected answer is something along the lines of:

```
P(Blue) = (case 1 + case 4) * 900 / 1000 = (1/4  + 1/4) * 900 / 1000 = 45 %
P(non-Blue) = (case 2 + case  3) * 100 / 1000 = (1/4 + 1/4) * 100 / 1000 = 5%
```

where remaining 50% is simply unknown, call it the error margin.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X,Y_1,Y_2,\ldots,Y_{1000} \in \{0,1\}$ denote the true color, and the responses, respectively. "Blue" is coded as a $1$, and vice versa. Assume that $p(x)$ is Bernoulli with parameter $p_x$. Assume that each $Y_i|X=1$ is Bernoull with parameter $p_1$, and assume $Y_i|X=0$ is Bernoulli with parameter $p_0$. Also, pick a prior for the parameters $\theta = (p_x,p_0,p_1)$.

You're looking for $p(\theta,x|y_{1:1000}) \propto p(\theta)p(x|\theta)\prod_{i=1}^{1000}p(y_i|x)$. Formulating it like this highlights the fact that (at least if you're a Bayesian) you need to choose priors for these three parameters. The Bayesian viewpoint is nice because you could take advantage of what you know about how often cars are blue, and what you know about peoples' tendencies to agree with reality.

Also you can generalize this model. For example what if the car changes colors, or if you're looking at a sequence of cars (then you have a sequence $\{x_i\}$), or if people are equipped differently to evaluate car colors ($\{y_i|x\}$ are not identically distributed), or if people are basing their decisions on what other people are saying, etc.

Answer (score -3):

The person that cannot see the car does not know it is scientifically proven to be blue.  The probability to he/she that the car is blue is 50/50 (it is blue, or it isn't).  Polling other people may influence this person's opinion but it does not change the probability that an unseen car is either blue, or not.

All of the above math determines the probability that your sample set can determine if it is blue.

Comment: I am not sure it is true that the probability that it is blue is 50/50. In fact, it is way less than 50, since it could be red, white, yellow, etc. The probability that a car picked at random is blue is way less than 50%.